# How to select one checkbox at a time in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, checkbox

I have implemented four checkboxes. Now, I want to select one checkbox at a time and if there's other checkbox selected, I want it deselected at the same time.

This is what I've tried but it selects all the checkboxes.

```
@IBAction func checkboxTapped(_ sender:UIButton){               
     if (sender.isSelected == false){
          sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "selected"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
          sender.isSelected = true;

     } else {
          sender.setImage(UIImage(named: "unselected"), for: UIControl.State.normal)
          sender.isSelected = false;
     }
}
```

Here, I have given same IBAction connection to all the checkboxes.

Comment: First of all you should use State .selected for when the checkbox is checked (and .normal otherwise), secondly I think that the setImage call is something you only make when you set up the button and not every time it is tapped on.

Comment: I am using @IBAction so whenever I'm tapping on the button it changes the image.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First create a set up function that sets the corresponding image for the button state.

(All code below was created in a playground so it might be a little different than yours)

```
private func setUp(button: UIButton) {
    button.setImage(UIImage.init(systemName: "checkmark.circle"), for: .selected)
    button.setImage(UIImage.init(systemName: "xmark.circle"), for: .normal)

    button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(checkboxTapped), for: .touchUpInside) //Not needed if you use a storyboard
}
```

Then call it from `viewDidLoad` in your view controller (I have my buttons in an array `buttons`)

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    buttons.forEach {
        setUp(button: $0)
        self.view.addSubview($0) //Not needed if you use a storyboard
    }
    buttons[0].isSelected = true
```

And then check your action method so it updates all buttons properly

```
@IBAction func checkboxTapped(_ sender:UIButton){
    for button in buttons {
        button.isSelected = false
    }

    sender.isSelected = true
}
```

If you are not using an array then replace my loops with calls to the individual buttons